# Could not adjust landscape view in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, orientation

I am using tab bar controller and handling login and logout functionality. Below is the code for adjusting tableViewCell in landscape mode for iPad.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellId = @"collabId";
    emptyCell *cell = (emptyCell *)[self.tableViewJoined dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if(!cell)
    {
        NSArray *nib;
        UIButton *buttonList;
        UIButton *buttonAttachment;
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"emptyCell" owner:self options:nil];
            buttonList = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 0, 30, 25)];
            buttonAttachment = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(290, 0, 30, 25)];
        }
        else
        {
            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
            {
                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"emptyCell_iPad" owner:self options:nil];
                buttonList = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(452, 0, 62, 25)];
                buttonAttachment = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(650, 0, 98, 25)];
            }
            else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            {
                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"emptyCell_iPad_Landscape" owner:self options:nil];
                buttonList = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(591, 0, 81, 24)];
                buttonAttachment = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(850, 0, 128, 24)];
            }
        }

        for (id object in nib)
        {
            if([object isKindOfClass:[emptyCell class]])
            {
                cell = (emptyCell *)object;
                break;
            }
        }


        [buttonList addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonListClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [buttonList setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonList];


        [buttonAttachment addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAttachmentClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [buttonAttachment setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonAttachment];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        SaveCollaboration *saveCollab = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.name.text = saveCollab.name;
        cell.project.text = saveCollab.project;
        cell.date.text = saveCollab.date;
        cell.invites.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", saveCollab.invites];
        cell.docsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", saveCollab.docsCount];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

One thing I noticed is that for the first page of logged in user, the following AppDelegate method is invoked thrice whenever I change its orientation. Other pages does not give the following method log thrice.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSLog(@"Orientation changed"); //Gets invoked thrice. Is this the reason why landscape cells don't get invoked?
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

I added a break point at

```
nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"emptyCell_iPad_Landscape" owner:self options:nil];
```

but it never got invoked.
You might refer following delegate method when the user logs in successfully.
I checked the identifier for `emptyCell_iPad_Landscape` nib and autolayout is unchecked.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    BOOL getFlag = delegate.flagToCheckLogin;
    if(!getFlag)
    {


        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:Nil];
            viewController.delegate = self;

            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:Nil];
            viewController.delegate = self;

            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
    }


}
```

Following methods are there in the logged in class..

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{


    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you insert any other breakpoints within the other if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == …) conditions of cellForRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: Yes I added a breakpoint for portrait and it got invoked.. Its working fine for portrait but not in landscape.

Comment: And when you rotate the device and update the table, does the portrait breakpoint also get invoked?

Comment: That was interesting. When I set my device in landscape before launching the app, portrait's breakpoint i.e. "emptyCell_iPad" was invoked. How? Why?

Comment: Quick question first: What about when you rotate the device while the app is running and update the table after the rotation?  Which breakpoint is called then?

Comment: Nevermind, that may not matter…  I think I may have an answer for you.  Will start writing it soon.

Comment: I added two breakpoints. One for "emptyCell_iPad" which is the protrait cell and other breakpoint for "emptyCell_iPad_Landscape". Whatever the orientation, "emptyCell_iPad_Landscape" never gets invoked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44226/discussion-between-optimus-prime-and-lyndsey-scott)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're misusing the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` function.  According to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM), `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` "Returns the interface idiom supported by the current device."  Typically this function is used to determine whether the device is an iPhone or an iPad, but since `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait` is in fact supported as is specified in your app delegate, it makes sense that this case will always be true.  (This is also probably why `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` in your appDelegate is, as you say, "invoked thrice"…since you're requesting the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` multiple times).

Instead of using `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` == … , you can either:

(1) Use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` to detect the device's current orientation:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    …

} else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

}
```

or

(2) Use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` to get the interface's current orientation:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    …

} else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

}
```

Note that solution #1 and #2 won't always return the same result.  #1 returns the *device's* current orientation.  #2 returns the *interface's* current orientation.  So one method may be more reliable for you than the other depending on what you need…  I'd recommend using method #2 in your case.

Comment: Your (1) method gives one warning : "Implicit conversion from enumeration type UIDeviceOrientation to different enumeration type UIInterfaceOrientation for on the line UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

while (2) is not working

Comment: Whoops, my bad -- #1 edited.  I accidentally typed UIInterfaceOrientation instead of UIDeviceOrientation.

Comment: And #2 will work upon device rotation. Upon the initial launch of the app, you may need to reload the table after the view appears in order to get the direction of the interface.

Comment: This is extremely weired. I get this error for (1) "Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]" Don't get this error when i use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()

Comment: Oh that's a completely different issue.  It means your cellForRowAtIndexPath is returning nil…  Hmm…I wonder why it works just for portrait?  Does your emptyCell_iPad_Landscape nib have a cell defined with the cell identifier you specified?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code before checking for if(!cell) in your cellForRowAtIndexPath. Now the breakpoint will get called.

```
static NSString *cellId = nil;
BOOL isPortraitOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        cellId = @"collabId-iPhone”;
    }
    else {
    if(isPortraitOrientation)
      {
       cellId = @"collabId-iPadPortrait”;
      }
    else
      {
       cellId = @"collabId-iPadLandscape”;
     }  
    }
    emptyCell *cell = (emptyCell *)[self.tableViewJoined dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() is not the proper way to check for device/interface orientations, so the proper breakpoint will still not be called.